# Service Temporarily Unavailable error on IIS 8.5 and ColdFusion 10

Tags: iis, coldfusion, cfml

In the midday the IIS server was just running fine, when I restarted it shows me this error

> Service Temporary Unavailable!
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>
> Jakarta/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.32 ()

Does anybody know how to fix this?

It was just running fine, didn't change anything to the connector nor IIS.

Thanks for the answers i gotten. I needed to restart Coldfusion, IIS, and the hosting PC itself to fix it. It won't go to the error anymore thanks!

Comment: The error looks pretty self explanatory, either a maintenance script is being run on the server or it is experiencing higher than average requests and has exceeded its capacity. If this is a managed server, i would recommend contacting your hosting provider. if you're managing it yourself, take a look into the Jakarta / ISAPI documentation which may be able to help you.

Comment: I would add the following 1) look in the event viewer for errors or other details. 2) I always restart CF at the same time I restart IIS and 3) things like maxworkerprocess may need to be adjusted. The default IIS settings are not always appropriate for you situation.

Comment: I have seen this issue and I don't know if I have fixed it, but I have made the changes at http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/tuning-coldfusion-10-iis-connector-configuration

Comment: Read this from the Adobe bug base: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3318104

Answer (score 2):

“Service unavailable” is an expected error with ColdFusion 10/11. This appears due to incorrect/missing connector tuning. Kindly visit to http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-11-iis-connector-tuning. The same blog is applicable for ColdFusion 10 as well.

Comment: Thanks Anit, I had the same problem today. Your suggestion worked for me, you save the day!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well.  You can Google a lot of information about it but it comes down to "Tuning ColdFusion 10 IIS Connector configuration".  Extensive information can be found in this page.

http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/tuning-coldfusion-10-iis-connector-configuration

My {CF-Home}/config/wsconfig/{some no}/workers.properties file looks like this:

```
    worker.list=cfusion

    worker.cfusion.type=ajp13
    worker.cfusion.host=localhost
    worker.cfusion.port=8012
    worker.cfusion.max_reuse_connections=250
    worker.cfusion.connection_pool_size=500
    worker.cfusion.connection_pool_timeout=60
```

I modified this line in {cf-home/cfusion/runtime/conf}/server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8012" protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionTimeout="60000" redirectPort="8445" maxThreads="500" tomcatAuthentication="false" />
```

I haven't had the problem since.

Your system may require further tweaking but give this a try.  Restart the CF Application service after you've updated the files.

Restart IIS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to put my 2 cents in here, I had this issue happen to me today running IIS 8.5 and ColdFusion 11 on Windows 8.

I had updated my Windows password, and my local web sites were giving me "Service Temporarily Unavailable" 503 errors. I had to open my local services and go to the properties tab for my ColdFusion server and update the password on the login tab.

Hope this helps someone.